# Free or open source Tree-grid for C#?

Tags: c#, user-interface, gridview, datagrid, treeview

Is there any [Tree-Grid](http://www.componentsource.com/products/componentone-vsflexgrid-pro/index.html) component that is freely available for a C# project? A Tree-grid is a combination of a tree view and a datagrid.
Every tree item represents a row in a table. Like this:

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[ObjectListView](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/) is great:

[image]
<sub>(source: [sourceforge.net](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/_images/treelistview.png))</sub>

Comment: This is it! And what incredible documentation! Damn easy to understand... http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/recipes.html#recipe-flavour

Comment: It should be noted that ObjectListView is licensed under the GPL, and therefore unsuitable for many commercial applications.

Comment: If only this was a WPF control...

Answer (score 3):

This one isn't bad :
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tree/TreeWithColumns.aspx

The best one I used is DevExpress's XtraTreeList, but it's not free...

Comment: What is not supported (yet):

*    Sorting of columns
*    Cell edit
*    Re-arranging columns at run time
*    Individual row height. Only fixed row height is supported

Answer (score 2):

This one seems to work as well: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/treelistview.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This one isn't free, but cheap enough.  Easy to work with if you can create a data column in your binding source that has the hierarchy in the form of a string - i.e. /root/parent/branch

[www.DigitalTools.com/gvt.aspx](http://www.DigitalTools.com/gvt.aspx)

[image]
<sub>(source: [digitaltools.com](http://www.digitaltools.com/Images/gvt.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I'v e heard that many developers praise [TreeViewAdv for .NET](http://sourceforge.net/projects/treeviewadv/).